# analyzing excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I wanted to analyze excel files and find out the data range ( min value, max value, min len, max len, blanks etc I want to create a new analysis file which would spit out these insights. I'm looking into the panda library to do this.

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('file.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='TestData')
```

How should I be proceeding ?

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy to get the minimum/maximum etc. The functions require numpy arrays though, so either slice each column of a dataframe, or cast the dataframe as a matrix

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Answer (score 0):

you can find out some of those statistics you are looking for - min, max, avg (mean), std. deviation for numeric columns using [describe()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) method

Demo:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/file.xlsx')

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
   a  b  c txt
0  8  5  2  dd
1  6  6  2  aa
2  3  7  9  cc
3  4  2  3  dd
4  3  3  5  cc

In [36]: df.describe()
Out[36]:
              a         b         c
count  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000
mean   4.800000  4.600000  4.200000
std    2.167948  2.073644  2.949576
min    3.000000  2.000000  2.000000
25%    3.000000  3.000000  2.000000
50%    4.000000  5.000000  3.000000
75%    6.000000  6.000000  5.000000
max    8.000000  7.000000  9.000000
```